# A name for a special class of complete lattices

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

Is there a name for sets $S\in\mathfrak{A}$ for a complete lattice $\mathfrak{A}$ such that for all $T\subseteq \mathfrak A$,
$$\bigvee T\in S \iff S\cap T\ne\varnothing?$$

Here $\bigvee$ is the join on the lattice $\mathfrak{A}$.

(Corrected: The name for $S$ not for $\mathfrak{A}$.)

Comment: This is a very different question than you originally asked.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the required name, but your condition is involved in the definition of an open subset in Scott topology:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity